# The background of "Can you pass me the salt"

Tags: spoken-english

My textbook says that  It is considered rude to reach out your hand and take something in front of others. Being Japanese myself, and when in Rome do as the Romans do is my policy, I'd rather they took the salt by themselves if the salt is within their reach. 
How can I express this politely? What should I say in reply?

Comment: Shall we assume you are a guest at family in the UK/USA?

Comment: @JamesK My original intention was when I speak to foreigners in Japan. But I now want to know what it would be in that case too.

Comment: If you are the guest, please do not reject someone's attempt to be polite in this manner.

Comment: Is it rude in Japan to reach in front of others or NOT? That's the point here.

Comment: @Lambie It is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese textbooks do like to make up rules for politeness that don't really exist.  If you can reach the salt without interrupting another person's eating, it's not rude if your hand is in front of other people.

This isn't some kind of special rule  that needs to be explained to Japanese people. It is no more rude for English people in England than it is for Japanese people in Japan. This is like a rule that "you must not steal food from other people's plates", not a rule like "you must not leave the chopsticks sticking out the rice".

People won't ask you to "pass the salt" if they believe they can reach it themselves.

The only reason someone would ask you to "pass the salt" is because that person believes it is much easier for you to reach it.  If it really isn't - for example if there is a salt cellar right in front of them, you can just point this out to them:

> John: Could you pass the salt?
> Taro: There's some just in front of you.

If there is salt that is easy for you to reach then just pass them the salt!

If there is no salt that you can reach, but there is some that a third person could reach, you can pass on the request.

> John: Could you pass the salt?
> Taro: Sure, ah, Mary, could you hand me the salt please?
> Mary: Here you are.
> Taro: Thanks,  John, here you are.

Answer (score 1):

I think to make the foreigners comfortable reaching in front of other people to take things in Japan, you're going to have to explain it directly:

*"In Japan, it's not considered rude to reach for things in front of other people, so you can go ahead and take the salt yourself if you like."*

Comment: Is it rude to do so in your country? I am now confused.

Comment: @Taro Yes, in the West, if you want something at the table that's in front of somebody else, you ask them to pass it. It's rude to put your arm in front of somebody else.

Comment: I'm confused to have received two contradictory answers.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I was taught the rule directly as a child. In Canada, if someone breaks that rule, people think either they are being rude, or they don't know the social rules.

Comment: I can't speak for James K, but where he says, "*If you can reach the salt **without interrupting another person's eating**, its not rude...*", I'm guessing if he were in Japan, he would have a stricter idea of what "interrupting someone else's eating" means than the average Japanese person would. For myself, I can say that if I were at the same table with the same people, but doing something other than eating, I would be more comfortable reaching in front of other people.

Answer (score -1):

In reply to "It is considered rude to reach out your hand and take something in front of others."
This is not a general western rule. This is an English/Anglo-Saxon rule and it's also adopted by the colonized countries of England, e.g. New Zealand and Australia.

In Europe, particularly in Austria and in Germany, they're more like Japan in this regard. They don't mind if someone stretch their arm -in a dinning table- in front of them to reach for something. It's considered rude to ask someone to pass you something, even if that something is far and requires that you stand up and stretch your arm to get it.

Comment: This is a site about the English language, not about norms, mores, and values.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/141746)

Comment: Do you have any sources for this? It's not considered rude to ask someone to pass you something in my experience in the UK and US, particularly if it is too far to reach easily. It can be considered rude to reach in front of someone, but unless you're pushing your arm in their face or trailing your sleeve in their food it's not serious. But still, if your reaching gets in someone's way, you should say "excuse me" or similar.